# List index out of range in loop with condition

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x

```
n = input("How many average temperatures do you want to put in?" + "\n").strip()
temperatures = []
differences = []
diff = 0

print('')
if int(n) > 0 :
    for x in range (int(n)):
        temp = input("Input a average temperature: " + "\n").strip()
        temperatures.append(int(temp))

    for y in range(len(temperatures)):
        if y == len(temperatures):
            break
        diff = temperatures[y+1] - temperatures[y]
        differences.append(diff)

    print(differences)
```

Getting a list index out of range error on this line:

```
diff = temperatures[y+1] - temperatures[y]
```

This line basically finds the difference between 2 numbers in my list, so I am telling it to take the index of the number infront and subtract it from the number before. I figured out eventually when it gets to the last number, the [y+1] ends up being out of range, so at the start of the loop I put the condition that will break out of the loop when it gets to the last number in the list.

But i'm still getting a index out of range error for some reason, and I don't understand why it's happening. Can anybody point out where i'm going wrong?

Comment: When `y=len(temperatures) - 1`, then `y + 1`...(you guessed it). Note that the last element of a list is indexed by the length of that list -1.

Comment: your `break` should be called `if y == len(temperatures)-1` since `range(len(x))` goes from `l -> len(x)-1` (`range` goes up to, but does not include, the parameter passed)

Comment: Note that you could also accomplish the desired result as follows:
`import numpy as np; differences = np.diff(temperatures)`

Comment: @dslack Why introducing new libraries when there's no need at all?

Comment: @nbro so as to get the job done in 1 line very efficiently.  If you prefer it could be a little cleaner with `from numpy import diff; differences = diff(temperatures)`.  You can write it yourself pretty easily, but numpy's diff() function is easy to use and efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this is a bit tricky. Below, I've written out an example list and the indices of that list.

```
a = [1, 56, 84, 32, -9]
     0   1   2   3   4
```

But...the length of the list is not 4, but 5. So `a[len(a)]`, which is equivalent to `a[5]`, will fail with an `IndexError`. Also, `range(len(temperatures))` will not include `len(temperatures)` itself, so the if conditional is never true *anyway*. In this section of your code,

```
for y in range(len(temperatures)):
    if y == len(temperatures):
        break
    diff = temperatures[y+1] - temperatures[y]
    differences.append(diff)
```

You need to change `if y == len(temperatures):` to `if y == len(temperatures)-1`. **Or**, and this is the better option, take out the if conditional entirely and change the loop to this:

```
for y in range(len(temperatures)-1):
    diff = temperatures[y+1] - temperatures[y]
    differences.append(diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
diff = temperatures[y+1] - temperatures[y]
```

When `y` reaches the last valid index in `temperatures`, the expression `y+1` will result in an index outside of the list, causing the error. Define the loop like this instead:

```
for y in range(len(temperatures)-1):
    diff = temperatures[y+1] - temperatures[y]
    differences.append(diff)
```

In this way, we won't step outside of the list of temperatures. Also notice that these lines are not doing what you imagine and can be deleted:

```
if y == len(temperatures):
  break
```

That's because `range()` goes from zero to `len(temperatures) - 1`, so `y` is never equal to `len(temperatures)`, and that's why you get an index out of bounds error.

Comment: But i put a condition before it does that that should break out of the loop when y reaches the last index?

Comment: @W.Ahmed the condition `y == len(temperatures)` is never true, remember that range stops in `len(temperatures) - 1` - for example, `range(0,3)` results in the values `0, 1, 2`.